# Problems importing a python module

Tags: python, import, module

im new to python and programming, i am reading a book and im learning about modules, but when i try to import my module, a python error says " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transaction' "
The module is a txt file named transaction.py, it is in my python main folder and im trying to import it this way:

```
from transaction import *
```

just as the book says to do, but it wont work in my code

what am i missing!!?

Comment: Is transaction.py in the same folder as your script?

Answer (score 0):

I think since you didn't upload a picture of your problem that you have a path problem
so try to put ur file transaction.py and the file you import from in the same folder
like this :

[image]

or you will need to import it by accessing the path

[image]